# Rails application issue after deployment - 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, weblogic

I'm new to RoR.
I was able to install Rails and host it in Webrick (Sample App with "Welcome" controller) in my windows.

Now i have a Unix Weblogic Server along with a dedicated domian. 
After exporting the `.WAR` file using Warbler, i accessed the `Oracle Admin Console` from where i deployed the .WAR file in the dedicated domain. I did all this for the Sample app with only the Welcome controller in it. 
But even after deploying the WAR file, on accessing the Domain along with the Port Number (:9002) i ended up with `404 file not found error` On looking at the server logs,there wasn't any records relating to any error. The Application must have been deployed properly. I assume that i must have missed out on some basic configurations in the routes.rb or similar files before deploying. Can anyone Guess what are all the possibilities and if possible can anyone help me by pointing to any tuts that cover the Steps to be carried out for configuration before deployment.
 do i need to install both JRuby and Rails inside the server before depolyment?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really guess with `Eror 404`  only.

You can try mapping your rails app rack config to a different base_uri.
All you need to do is wrap the existing 'run' command in a map block

try doing this in your rails '**config.ru**' file:

```
map '/mydepartment' do
    run Myapp::Application
end
```

Now when you 'rails server' the app should be at **localhost:3000/mydepartment** . 
Not sure if this will give you the desired outcome, but worth a try.

One more thing you also add this to your config/environments/production.rb and config/environments/development.rb (if on production mode):

```
config.action_controller.asset_path = proc { |path| "/abc#{path}" }
```

otherwise when you call your helpers such as stylesheet_link_tag in your views, they will generate links without the "/abc".

Also, find some guides you may refer for good support.

[JRubyOnRailsOnBEAWeblogic](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyOnRailsOnBEAWeblogic).

[Use JRuby with JMX for Oracle WebLogic Server 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/jruby-wls-jmx-356114.html)

Let me know if it is not resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what are all the packages that i need to have installed in the Unix server? I already have Jruby+Weblogic, when i tried to install Rails i got a dependency error, so didn't proceed further. Is the Rails+Jruby+Weblogic package configuration necessary? if so, what kind of configuration should be done?